# C# Authorize.net Create Profile Issue

Tags: c#, authorize.net

The following code is charging the card, however it is not creating the profile....any tips?  I'm assuming I'm missing something, or using the wrong Type...

```
            var opaqueData = new opaqueDataType { dataDescriptor = "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT", dataValue = paymentNonce };

            //standard api call to retrieve response
            var paymentType = new paymentType { Item = opaqueData };

            var transactionRequest = new transactionRequestType
            {
                transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString(),    // authorize and capture transaction
                amount = paymentAmount,
                payment = paymentType,
                customer = new customerDataType()
                {
                    type = customerTypeEnum.individual,
                    id = userID.ToString()
                },
                profile = new customerProfilePaymentType()
                {
                    createProfile = true
                }
            };

            var request = new createTransactionRequest { transactionRequest = transactionRequest };

            // instantiate the contoller that will call the service
            var controller = new createTransactionController(request);
            const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
            const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
            controller.Execute();

            // get the response from the service (errors contained if any)
            var response = controller.GetApiResponse();
```

**UPDATE:**
Since apparently OpaqueData is not allowed, I changed it to make the profile manually.  I am getting the following Error: "Error: I00001  Successful."

```
// Add Payment method to Customer.
                        customerPaymentProfileType opaquePaymentProfile = new customerPaymentProfileType();
                        opaquePaymentProfile.payment = paymentType;
                        opaquePaymentProfile.customerType = customerTypeEnum.individual;
                        var request2 = new createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest
                        {
                            paymentProfile = opaquePaymentProfile,
                            validationMode = validationModeEnum.none,
                            customerProfileId = userID.ToString()
                        };
                        var controller2 = new createCustomerPaymentProfileController(request2);
                        controller2.Execute();

                        //Send Request to EndPoint
                        createCustomerPaymentProfileResponse response2 = controller2.GetApiResponse();
                        if (response2 != null && response2.messages.resultCode == messageTypeEnum.Ok)
                        {
                            if (response2 != null && response2.messages.message != null)
                            {
                                //Console.WriteLine("Success, createCustomerPaymentProfileID : " + response.customerPaymentProfileId);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Utility.AppendTextToFile("Error: " + response.messages.message[0].code + "  " + response.messages.message[0].text, Server.MapPath("/pub/auth.txt"));

                        }
```

**Update #2**
Very confused as auth.net documentation says this code means success...so why don't I see the CIM payment method created??? [RESPONSE CODE DOCS](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=I00001)

**Update #3**
So I was printing out the main response message instead of the CIM request message, duh.  The actual error was: "E00114  Invalid OTS Token."
Based on the the documentation, that error is usually from a used Key, so I am now generating 2 keys (One to process and One to store via CIM) but am now getting this error: "E00040  The record cannot be found."....Any ideas?

Comment: What response you are getting from API? How do you verify if the profile is created or not? Did you debug the code?

Comment: I️ am getting a successful creation of the transaction. I️ am checking in the auth.net panel to see if there are any profiles created.

Comment: Show your response from Authorize.Net or else we are unable to assist you

Comment: This is in a web service so it took a bit, The one message I get is "Customer profile creation failed. This payment method does not support profile creation."  So I'm guessing I can't make a customer payment profile from the Accept SDK encoded card?  Is my only choice to send raw credit card details to the server?  I thought accept SDK was required when using a phone app?

Comment: I updated the question, since from what I am seeing I have to manually create this profile since I am using opaque data.

Comment: ***Post the entire actual response that you receive***

Comment: How do I get that?  Sorry can't seem to see how to get the raw response from the C# SDK...

Comment: @JohnConde See above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to this question is:

1. You can not auto create a payment profile using opaque card data, so the answer is to make it manually once you have a successful charge.
2. You can not use the same opaque card data to charge and store, as they are one time use, so for my web method I ended up passing 2 opaque data keys.
3. You have to make different calls for setting up a brand new customer and an existing customer just adding a new card.  I have pasted an excerpt of my end solution below:

   ```
        ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.RunEnvironment = (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authorize-Live"].ToUpper() == "TRUE" ? AuthorizeNet.Environment.PRODUCTION : AuthorizeNet.Environment.SANDBOX);
       // define the merchant information (authentication / transaction id)

       ApiOperationBase<ANetApiRequest, ANetApiResponse>.MerchantAuthentication = new merchantAuthenticationType()

       {

           name = (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authorize-Live"].ToUpper() == "TRUE" ? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authorize-LoginID"] : System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authorize-LoginID-SandBox"]),

           ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.transactionKey,

           Item = (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authorize-Live"].ToUpper() == "TRUE" ? System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authorize-TransactionKey"] : System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authorize-TransactionKey-SandBox"])

       };



       if (paymentNonce.Trim() != "")

       {

           //set up data based on transaction

           var opaqueData = new opaqueDataType { dataDescriptor = "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT", dataValue = paymentNonce };



           //standard api call to retrieve response

           var paymentType = new paymentType { Item = opaqueData };



           var transactionRequest = new transactionRequestType

           {

               transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString(),    // authorize and capture transaction

               amount = paymentAmount,

               payment = paymentType,

               customer = new customerDataType()

               {

                   type = customerTypeEnum.individual,

                   id = "YOUR_DB_USERID"

               },

               profile = new customerProfilePaymentType()

               {

                   createProfile = false

               }

           };



           var request = new createTransactionRequest { transactionRequest = transactionRequest };



           // instantiate the contoller that will call the service

           var controller = new createTransactionController(request);

           const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;

           const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;

           ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;

           controller.Execute();



           // get the response from the service (errors contained if any)

           var response = controller.GetApiResponse();



           //validate

           if (response != null)

           {

               if (response.messages.resultCode == messageTypeEnum.Ok)

               {

                   if (response.transactionResponse.messages != null)

                   {

                       responseData.Success = true;

                       transactionID = response.transactionResponse.transId;


                       string merchID = "STORED AUTHORIZE.NET CUSTOMERID, return blank string if none!";

                       var opaqueData2 = new opaqueDataType { dataDescriptor = "COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT", dataValue = paymentNonce2 };



                       //standard api call to retrieve response

                       var paymentType2 = new paymentType { Item = opaqueData2 };

                       customerPaymentProfileType opaquePaymentProfile = new customerPaymentProfileType();

                       opaquePaymentProfile.payment = paymentType2;

                       opaquePaymentProfile.customerType = customerTypeEnum.individual;





                       if (merchID == "")

                       {
                           // CREATE NEW AUTH.NET AIM CUSTOMER
                           List<customerPaymentProfileType> paymentProfileList = new List<customerPaymentProfileType>();

                           paymentProfileList.Add(opaquePaymentProfile);

                           customerProfileType customerProfile = new customerProfileType();

                           customerProfile.merchantCustomerId = "YOUR_DB_USERID";



                           customerProfile.paymentProfiles = paymentProfileList.ToArray();



                           var cimRequest = new createCustomerProfileRequest { profile = customerProfile, validationMode = validationModeEnum.none };



                           var cimController = new createCustomerProfileController(cimRequest);          // instantiate the contoller that will call the service

                           cimController.Execute();



                           createCustomerProfileResponse cimResponse = cimController.GetApiResponse();

                           if (cimResponse != null && cimResponse.messages.resultCode == messageTypeEnum.Ok)

                           {

                               if (cimResponse != null && cimResponse.messages.message != null)

                               {
                                   // STORE cimResponse.customerProfileId IN DATABASE FOR USER

                               }

                           }

                           else

                           {

                               for (int i = 0; i < cimResponse.messages.message.Length; i++)

                                   Utility.AppendTextToFile("New Error (" + merchID + ") #" + i.ToString() + ": " + cimResponse.messages.message[i].code + "  " + cimResponse.messages.message[i].text, Server.MapPath("/pub/auth.txt"));



                           }

                       }

                       else

                       {
                           // ADD PAYMENT PROFILE TO EXISTING AUTH.NET AIM CUSTOMER
                           var cimRequest = new createCustomerPaymentProfileRequest

                           {

                               paymentProfile = opaquePaymentProfile,

                               validationMode = validationModeEnum.none,

                               customerProfileId = merchID.Trim()

                           };

                           var cimController = new createCustomerPaymentProfileController(cimRequest);

                           cimController.Execute();



                           //Send Request to EndPoint

                           createCustomerPaymentProfileResponse cimResponse = cimController.GetApiResponse();

                           if (cimResponse != null && cimResponse.messages.resultCode == messageTypeEnum.Ok)

                           {

                               if (cimResponse != null && cimResponse.messages.message != null)

                               {

                                   //Console.WriteLine("Success, createCustomerPaymentProfileID : " + response.customerPaymentProfileId);

                               }

                           }

                           else

                           {

                               for (int i = 0; i < cimResponse.messages.message.Length; i++)

                                   Utility.AppendTextToFile("Add Error  (" + merchID + ") #" + i.ToString() + ": " + cimResponse.messages.message[i].code + "  " + cimResponse.messages.message[i].text, Server.MapPath("/pub/auth.txt"));



                           }

                       }

                   }

                   else

                   {

                       responseData.Message = "Card Declined";

                       responseData.Success = false;

                       if (response.transactionResponse.errors != null)

                       {

                           responseData.Message = response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorText;

                       }

                   }

               }

               else

               {

                   responseData.Message = "Failed Transaction";

                   responseData.Success = false;

                   if (response.transactionResponse != null && response.transactionResponse.errors != null)

                   {

                       responseData.Message = response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorText;

                   }

                   else

                   {

                       responseData.Message = response.messages.message[0].text;

                   }

               }

           }

           else

           {

               responseData.Message = "Failed Transaction, Try Again!";

               responseData.Success = false;

           }

       }

       else

       {
           // RUN PAYMENT WITH STORED PAYMENT PROFILE ID
           customerProfilePaymentType profileToCharge = new customerProfilePaymentType();

           profileToCharge.customerProfileId = CustomerID;

           profileToCharge.paymentProfile = new paymentProfile { paymentProfileId = PaymentID };



           var transactionRequest = new transactionRequestType

           {

               transactionType = transactionTypeEnum.authCaptureTransaction.ToString(),    

               amount = paymentAmount,

               profile = profileToCharge

           };



           var request = new createTransactionRequest { transactionRequest = transactionRequest };



           // instantiate the collector that will call the service

           var controller = new createTransactionController(request);

           controller.Execute();



           // get the response from the service (errors contained if any)

           var response = controller.GetApiResponse();



           //validate

           if (response != null)

           {

               if (response.messages.resultCode == messageTypeEnum.Ok)

               {

                   if (response.transactionResponse.messages != null)

                   {

                       responseData.Success = true;

                       transactionID = response.transactionResponse.transId;



                   }

                   else

                   {

                       responseData.Message = "Card Declined";

                       responseData.Success = false;

                       if (response.transactionResponse.errors != null)

                       {

                           responseData.Message = response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorText;

                       }

                   }

               }

               else

               {

                   responseData.Message = "Failed Transaction";

                   responseData.Success = false;

                   if (response.transactionResponse != null && response.transactionResponse.errors != null)

                   {

                       responseData.Message = response.transactionResponse.errors[0].errorText;

                   }

                   else

                   {

                       responseData.Message = response.messages.message[0].text;

                   }

               }

           }

           else

           {

               responseData.Message = "Failed Transaction, Try Again!";

               responseData.Success = false;

           }

       }
   ```